# imaplib.IMAP4.error: got more than 20480 bytes when configured A gmail account for a Frappe Project

Tags: python, email, gmail, erpnext, frappe

I have configured one Gmail id for default inbox inside email Account list, I am geting an Error . When a new email is recieved in the email inbox.
Step to reproduce :

1. configure new email to Email Account doctype
2. send a mail to the mail id
   The mail should be added in Communication Doctype , But some Error showing in the Error Log as 'pull_from_email_account'

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/imaplib.py", line 1022, in _command_complete
    typ, data = self._get_tagged_response(tag, expect_bye=logout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/imaplib.py", line 1148, in _get_tagged_response
    self._get_response()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/imaplib.py", line 1050, in _get_response
    resp = self._get_line()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/imaplib.py", line 1158, in _get_line
    line = self.readline()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/imaplib.py", line 316, in readline
    raise self.error("got more than %d bytes" % _MAXLINE)
imaplib.IMAP4.error: got more than 20480 bytes
```

versions that I use

erpnext 12.30.1
frappe 12.27.0
python 3.8

The mails coming to the configured mails inbox, The mail should be shown in the communication list inside the 'Communication' doctype , But its not coming in the list and an error coming in Error Log list Titled 'pull_from_email_account' Error

Comment: please edit your question and include [example] I need to see your code

Answer (score 0):

RFC 1939 limits POP3 line length to **512** characters. For the Python standard library `poplib`, they have selected **2048** to be on the safe side. Frappe overrides this limit to **20480** (40x the RFC limit) to be on the even safer side.

You can override the limit by monkey patching `poplib._MAXLINE` to a higher number that suits your requirement by making a separate Frappe App, or update it directly in Frappe's [Email Module](https://github.com/frappe/frappe/blob/version-12/frappe/email/receive.py#L553).